# UIBarButtonItem with portrait and landscape images may show portrait image for landscape orientation

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, landscape

In iOS 7, I am showing a UIBarButtonItem in the navigation bar of a UINavigationController. The UIBarButtonItem has an image for portrait orientation and another image for landscape orientation:

```
// "self" refers to the UINavigationController
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:portraitImage landscapeImagePhone:landscapeImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:NULL];
```

If you just rotate the interface, the correct image is used for the interface orientation. However, if the view for the UINavigationController first appears in landscape orientation (say, by presenting it in landscape orientation or by dismissing a view controller that is covering it up in landscape orientation), the **portrait** image is used instead! Why is this happening? Is this a framework bug? If so, is there a way to work around this, so the landscape image will always be shown for landscape orientation?

Comment: Are you testing on an ipad?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem.

I found a solution over at [UIBarButtonItem with separate portrait and landscape images - layoutSubviews not called when popping a view controller from UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569478/uibarbuttonitem-with-separate-portrait-and-landscape-images-layoutsubviews-not?rq=1) that sounded really promising, but it doesn't work for me. I'm going to go with changing the image on orientation change instead. Please post your solution if you find something better.

The landscape image works all of the time on UIToolbar, but not UINavigationBar. With UINavigationBar, I get the problem you state. I also had the problem that if I tapped the button in landscape, it would change to its portrait version.